# Conexión PHP - SQL

Tags: php

tengo un archivo llamado "conexion.php" con el siguiente código:

```
class conexion{

private $servidor="localhost";
private $usuario="root";
private $contrasenia="";
private $conexion;

public function _construct(){

    try {
        $this->conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=album",$this->usuario,$this->contrasenia);
        $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRORMODE, PDO::ERRORMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        return "Falla de conexión".$e;
    }
}

public function ejecutar($sql){
    $this->conexion->exec($sql);
    return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
}
```

}

luego tengo un archivo llamado: "portafolio.php" con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php include("cabecera.php"); ?>
```

ejecutar($sql);
?>

y cuando hago la prueba me tira el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exec() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\conexion.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\portafolio.php(7): conexion->ejecutar('INSERT INTO `pr...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\conexion.php on line 21

que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Que no se conecta, eso es lo que pasa. Cambia la línea del `return "Falla de conexión".$e;`, y pon esto en su lugar: `print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";`, porque tal como tienes el código ahora mismo es probable que el error que debería mostrarse no vaya a ninguna parte, pues no lo tienes en cuenta. Tu prueba y a ver que nuevo error te sale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De entrada el constructor lleva dos `_`, no uno, o sea: `__construct`, por otra parte, nunca creas una instancia de tu clase `conexion` en el contexto, ni tampoco veo que incluyas el archivo de la clase.

Prueba a crear la clase así:

```
class conexion {

    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $contrasenia="";
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
    
        try {
                $options = array (
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
                );        
                $this->conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=album;charset=UTF8",$this->usuario,$this->contrasenia,$options);
        }catch (PDOException $e){
                #Quitar esto en producción
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    public function ejecutar($sql){
        if ($this->conexion) {
            $this->conexion->exec($sql);
            return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            return "No hay conexión";
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, en el contexto, incluye el archivo de la clase (asumo que se llama `conexion.php` y crea la instancia para poder llamar al método:

```
<?php 
    include("cabecera.php"); 
    include_once("conexion.php");
    $sql="AQUÍ TU INSTRUCCIÓN SQL";
    $pdo=new conexion();
    echo $pdo->ejecutar($sql); 
?>
```

Comment: Gracias mil, me ayudaste mucho

Comment: @DanyRodriguez no tienes que cerrar la pregunta, el sentido del sitio es que futuros usuarios con un problema parecido encuentren ayuda para resolverlo. Puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te haya ayudado a resolver el problema y puedes valorar una o más respuesta positivamente pulsando en la flecha que apunta hacia arriba, en la parte izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre uso esta estructura, podrias adaptarla a tu codigo

```
<?php

    class Connection {

        function connectdb() {

            //attributes

            $user = 'usuario';
            $pass = 'contraseña';

            global $connect;

            //methods

            // Set DSN

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basededatos;';

            //Create a PDO instance

            try {

                $connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


            }catch(PDOexception $e) {

                print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                
            }

        }

    }
    
    //Estas lineas son las que ejecutan la conexión, podrias sacarlas 
    $newconnection = new Connection();
    $newconnection->connectdb();


?>
```